Visualization of phonon modes in siesta
When I try to visualize phonon modes using vib2xsf utility in siesta (DFT code) for a nanowire system, the utility gives an error "Error reading real part of eigenvector          1  iat=           8". Am I making a mistake while running FC calculation in siesta? Please, suggest the appropriate method to do this.
